# Website embedded video stream in VLC

Tags: video, streaming, vlc

Sometims I’m watching live events on websites that have an embedded flash video player.

Is it possible to take the stream to a native player such as VLC?

If so, what would be the steps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the web inspector and look in the resource list for the active network connection (indicated by the spinning pinwheel next to the resource) as this is usually the stream file.

Clicking the resource will show the Full URL under the Location section of the resource inspector. This URL can be added in VLC.

[image]

Note that some URLs won't be able to be played in VLC due to licensing restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the source URL, then you can stream it with VLC.

VLC- File- Open Network.

[image: stream]

Comment: Any idea how to fetch the url of a stream (from a flash embed)?

Comment: Many ways to do that, if it is not confidential, give me the web site link, and I look for it to tell you how I found it. Simplest, when you hover over the video window there is a pop up bottom left showing the link. Some, show it if you right click on the video window ect...

Comment: The URLs tend to change, but atm here's an example of a streaming flash video: http://gratisvoetbalstreams.nl/streamplayer3.php

Comment: The link you gave me would download a player? I do not do that since I do not need players. Inspecting the website it has to many Spams on it, not a place to be (for me). What browser are you using?

Comment: I don't think it downloads anything for you, but if you don't have the flash player installed maybe it prompts about that. It was just an example for a streaming service, inserting that URL in VLC doesn't do much unfortunately.. :/  I'm on Firefox 32.0.

Comment: Sorry to disagree, any play button I click on that site requires downloading some 3d party player (basically junk) and I am 101% sure I do not need any new players installed. I just do not do that for security reasons.

Comment: I totally understand! I think I've got enough info from you to find out how to do this anyhow. Thanks a lot!

Comment: FYI, I use the Ant Video add on to the Firefox, so anything that plays in my screen I can download, just in case you are interested.

Comment: The linked stream provided by @Numbers does not require any additional plugins—it's just JWPlayer (Flash) playing a live broadcast.